# Mongoose insertMany never returns when using async / await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

I am facing a weird issue and after googling and searching StackOverflow for a few hours I submit this question in the hopes that a) I will find the answer myself immediately after or b) a brilliant mind will come along and save me.

I am querying the Steam API through a Bull task in Express. Everything worked well until I changed my code to use async / await and now Mongoose's `insertMany` does not return anything.

Here is the Bull task processor file:

```
const SteamApp = require('./../models/steamapp.model');
const SteamAPI = require('./../lib/steam.lib');

module.exports = async function(job) {
  console.log("--------------------------- STARTING THE JOB!");
  await job.progress(5);

  try {
    const steamData = await new SteamAPI().getAppList();
    await job.progress(10);

    if(steamData && steamData.applist && steamData.applist.apps && steamData.applist.apps.length) {
      const appsPerProgressPoint = Math.ceil(steamData.applist.apps.length / 90);
      let appList = steamData.applist.apps;
      let numberOfAppsInserted = 0;
      let taskProgress = 10;

      while(appList.length) {
        const appsToInsert = appList.splice(0, appsPerProgressPoint);
        const documentsInserted = await SteamApp.insertMany(appsToInsert, { ordered: false });

        if(documentsInserted && documentsInserted.length) {
          console.log(`Inserted ${documentsInserted.length} new Steam apps`);
          numberOfAppsInserted += documentsInserted.length;
        } else {
          console.log("Inserted no apps this time.");
        }

        taskProgress++;
        await job.progress(taskProgress);
      }

      return `${numberOfAppsInserted} new apps were inserted`;
    } else {
      console.log("Received the following data from Steam: ", steamData);
      return 'The Steam app list was empty or there was an error.';
    }
  } catch(err) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(`The error ${err} occurred and the job failed.`));
  }
}
```

The SteamApp model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const steamAppSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  appid: { type: Number, unique: true },
  name: String,
  type: String,
  isFree: Boolean
} );

module.exports = mongoose.model('SteamApp', steamAppSchema);
```

The SteamAPI helper:

const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

```
module.exports = class SteamAPI {
  apiKey;
  parameters;
  url;
  
  constructor() {
    this.apiKey = process.env.MASTER_STEAMID;
  }

  async getAppList() {
    this.url = 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/';
    this.parameters = {
      key: this.apiKey
    };
    return await this.makeRequest();
  }

  async makeRequest() {
    console.log(`About to make the request to ${this.url}`);

    try {
      let steamResponse = await axios.get(this.url, this.parameters);
      return steamResponse.data;
    } catch(connectionError) {
      console.error("Could not make Steam request: " + connectionError.message);
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to keep this as a minimal code sample so error control, validations, etc. might be missing. The code stops at the `const documentsInserted = await SteamApp.insertMany(appsToInsert, { ordered: false });` line and the `insertMany` function never inserts or return anything. Note that if I use the insertMany callback instead, the function works properly, the data is inserted and I get what was inserted inside the callback.

The `axios.get` function also uses await and works properly. So my gut feeling is telling me it's something to do with Mongoose but I cannot figure what exactly.

Using the following:

- Node 12.18.4
- Mongoose 5.10.7
- MongoDB 3.6.3
- Express 4.16.1
- Bull 3.18.0
- Axios 0.20.0

Edit: `appsToInsert` is an array of objects, each containing two properties: `appid`, a number, and `name`, a string. So in short

```
appsToInsert = [{
  appid: 3939,
  name: 'A random name'
}, {
  appid: 298489,
  name: 'Yet another game name'
}, ...];
```

UPDATE 1: Trying lots of different things in order to better understand the issue, I moved the code from the Bull external processor directly inside the `this.queue.process` inline function. Everything works now. So I guess the problem is related to how Bull manages async / await operations inside of the child process sandbox. I will continue fiddling with this to see if I can come up with a solution using an external processor.

Comment: What's the structure of `appsToInsert`?

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention, thanks for reminding me. I will edit the question to add details about `appsToInsert`.

Comment: You sure `appToInsert` matches the schema perfectly? Also, you said that it works when you're using the `insertMany` callback. Can you also show us that code?

Comment: That would almost double the length of the post. I'll try to set up a gist or public github repository instead.

Comment: Ok. Please. So we can know what might be wrong.